# Custom Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dropdown

i'm searching for a dropdown menu like this:

http://www.staples.it/

You can active it pressing on " Forniture per ufficio " or " informatica ".

How can I push down a div with the dropdown, how I can block it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please first read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a block with relative position under the menu and height: 0;
Then on Click event you just use function [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Ex:

```
$(".selector").slideDown();
```

UPDATE

Here is the similar script for you https://jsfiddle.net/c2nuj88u/