# Side nav-bar dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to make a drop-down section on a navigation bar, for example: click on one of the options such as 'products' and have a drop-down with a list of products and when you click again the list disappears. Is this possible using HTML/CSS/JS, if so, how?

I am using the `ul` and `li` tags currently to make the navigation bar on my website, I'm not sure if there are other ways to do it or not.

Any help would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199837/custom-dropdown-menu. Then when you user selects the final drop down selection, hide them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to create a dropdown menu.
I'd like to use a nearly pure CSS/HTML method for your challenge.

Consider trying something like this:

```css
/*  CSS  */
ul.navigation > li{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
}

ul.navigation > li > ul{
  position:absolute;
  background:lightgray;
  display:none;
  left:0px;
  top:20px;
}

ul.navigation > li > a:focus + ul{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Bottles</li>
      <li>Cans</li>
      <li>Cups</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

First we make sure the nav link we want to use as a toggle rather than a link has a `href="javascript:void(0)"`. This will prevent the default behavior of the `a` element from navigating away from the page.

Next we need to hide the submenus by adding a `display:none` to the nested ul.

Then to display our submenu, we require the user to focus on a given navigation's anchor tag which sets the display property of the submenu to block.

Example:
http://codepen.io/eoghanTadhg/pen/ZWxXEb